# CancellationTokenSource need advice

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a class Worker like this:

```
public class Worker
{
    private List<SomeObject> _someObjectList = null;

    public Worker(SomeObject someObjectList)
    {
        _someObjectList = someObjectList;
    }

    public void Run(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Some time-consuming operation here
        foreach(var elem in _someObjectList)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            elem.DoSomethingLong();
        }
    }
}
```

And a form I use worker in:

```
public partial class SomeForm : Form
{
    private Worker _worker = null;

    public SomeForm(Worker worker)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _worker = worker;
    }

    async void RunButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // I have a way to cancel worker from MyForm but 
        //  I would like to be able to cancel it directly from Worker 
        //   so object would be intuitive.
        var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => _worker.Run(tokenSource.Token), tokenSource.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
        await task;     
    }
}
```

I need a more clear solution to cancel the worker. Like this:

```
_worker.Cancel();
```

I would also like to pause and resume the worker like this:

```
_worker.Pause();
_worker.Resume();
```

Since I instantiate CancellationTokenSource outside Worker class I see no way to implement my own Cancel method. I have already implemented Pause and Resume with CancellationToken like this(I feel like it's a very bad idea but it works):

```
public class Worker
{
    private List<SomeObject> _someObjectList = null;
    private CancellationTokenSource _pauseToken = null;

    public bool Paused { get; private set; }

    public Worker(SomeObject someObjectList)
    {
        _someObjectList = someObjectList;
    }

    public void Run(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Some time-consuming operation here
        foreach(var elem in _someObjectList)
        {
            if(Paused)
                _pauseToken.Token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(Timeout.Infinite);

            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            elem.DoSomethingLong();
        }
    }

    public void Pause()
    {
        if(!Paused)
        {
            // For pausing and resuming...
            _pauseToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

            Paused = true;

        }
    }

    public void Resume()
    {
        if(Paused && _pauseToken != null)
        {
            _pauseToken.Cancel();

            Paused = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I need advice on how to implement Cancel method and Resume/Pause method the most propriate way.

Comment: Cancellation token for pausing looks like misuse to me, why not just ManualResetEvent?
As for cancellation - If you want to support cancellation in two ways (CancellationToken and Cancel() method), you need to create a new cancellationtoken source internally, which will be either cancelled by original CancellationToken passed to you (token.Register(() => internalTokenSource.Cancel()) or by Cancel() method: internalTokenSource.Cancel().

Comment: @MiklX but how would I assign this internalTokenSource.Token to  the task I created outside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to encapsulate the cancellation behavior in the `Worker` class, it will obviously have to have some mechanism for calling `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()` at the appropriate time, on the appropriate object. There are two obvious ways to implement this:

1. Embed the `CancellationTokenSource` object in the `Worker` class itself.
2. Provide a callback mechanism by which when the `Worker.Cancel()` method is called, it delegates the actual operation to some other class.

The second approach seems arbitrarily convoluted to me, while the first seems like a natural fit for a class which you want for itself to expose a `Cancel()` method.

As for pausing and resuming, I agree with the comment below your question suggesting that using `CancellationTokenSource` is a misuse of that type for this purpose. That said, in modern C# code there is no reason to use something like `ManualResetEvent` and the concomitant house-keeping code that would have to accompany that.

Instead, you can implement your `Run()` method as `async`, and have it `await` if and when a `TaskCompletionSource` is available. Then it would have public methods `Pause()` and `Resume()`, where the `Pause()` method would create the `TaskCompletionSource` object, while the `Resume()` method would set the result on that object.

Doing it this way, you can implement your `Run()` method normally, without any additional effort to write house-keeping code to allow the method to pause and resume. The compiler will generate all that code for you, using the `await` statement(s) as the place(s) where the method may return from when paused and then resume execution later.

The alternative would be to write all that house-keeping code yourself (easy to make a mistake), or not even return from the `Run()` method but instead just block the thread until the operation is resumed (which needlessly ties up a thread while you're waiting for the user to release it).

If you have just a single task and a very simple user scenario, this may be overkill. Blocking the thread might be sufficient. But if you have more complex scenarios, this approach will fully support those while still providing for most efficient use of the thread pool.

Here is a short code example that demonstrates the techniques I describe above:

**Worker.cs**

```
class Worker
{
    private static readonly TimeSpan _ktotalDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    private const int _kintervalCount = 20;

    public bool IsPaused { get { return _pauseCompletionSource != null; } }
    public event EventHandler IsPausedChanged;

    private readonly object _lock = new object();
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancelSource;
    private volatile TaskCompletionSource<object> _pauseCompletionSource;

    public async Task Run(IProgress<int> progress)
    {
        _cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        TimeSpan sleepDuration = TimeSpan.FromTicks(_ktotalDuration.Ticks / _kintervalCount);

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i += (100 / _kintervalCount))
        {
            progress.Report(i);
            Thread.Sleep(sleepDuration);
            _cancelSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            TaskCompletionSource<object> pauseCompletionSource;

            lock (_lock)
            {
                pauseCompletionSource = _pauseCompletionSource;
            }

            if (pauseCompletionSource != null)
            {
                RaiseEvent(IsPausedChanged);

                try
                {
                    await pauseCompletionSource.Task;
                }
                finally
                {
                    lock (_lock)
                    {
                        _pauseCompletionSource = null;
                    }
                    RaiseEvent(IsPausedChanged);
                }
            }
        }

        progress.Report(100);

        lock (_lock)
        {
            _cancelSource.Dispose();
            _cancelSource = null;

            // Just in case pausing lost the race with cancelling or finishing
            _pauseCompletionSource = null;
        }
    }

    public void Cancel()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (_cancelSource != null)
            {
                if (_pauseCompletionSource == null)
                {
                    _cancelSource.Cancel();
                }
                else
                {
                    _pauseCompletionSource.SetCanceled();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void Pause()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (_pauseCompletionSource == null)
            {
                _pauseCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Resume()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (_pauseCompletionSource != null)
            {
                _pauseCompletionSource.SetResult(null);
            }
        }
    }

    private void RaiseEvent(EventHandler handler)
    {
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

**Form1.cs**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Worker _worker;

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Progress<int> progress = new Progress<int>(i => progressBar1.Value = i);
        _worker = new Worker();

        _worker.IsPausedChanged += (sender1, e1) =>
        {
            Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                button3.Enabled = !_worker.IsPaused;
                button4.Enabled = _worker.IsPaused;
            }));
        };

        button1.Enabled = false;
        button2.Enabled = button3.Enabled = true;

        try
        {
            await Task.Run(() => _worker.Run(progress));

            // let the progress bar catch up before we clear it
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Operation was cancelled");
        }

        progressBar1.Value = 0;
        button2.Enabled = button3.Enabled = button4.Enabled = false;
        button1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _worker.Cancel();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _worker.Pause();
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _worker.Resume();
    }
}
```

**Form1.Designer.cs**

```
partial class Form1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.progressBar1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar();
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.button3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.button4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // progressBar1
        // 
        this.progressBar1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.progressBar1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 42);
        this.progressBar1.Name = "progressBar1";
        this.progressBar1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(427, 23);
        this.progressBar1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 13);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.button1.Text = "Start";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        // 
        // button2
        // 
        this.button2.Enabled = false;
        this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(94, 13);
        this.button2.Name = "button2";
        this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button2.TabIndex = 2;
        this.button2.Text = "Cancel";
        this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
        // 
        // button3
        // 
        this.button3.Enabled = false;
        this.button3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(175, 13);
        this.button3.Name = "button3";
        this.button3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button3.TabIndex = 3;
        this.button3.Text = "Pause";
        this.button3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button3.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button3_Click);
        // 
        // button4
        // 
        this.button4.Enabled = false;
        this.button4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(256, 13);
        this.button4.Name = "button4";
        this.button4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button4.TabIndex = 4;
        this.button4.Text = "Resume";
        this.button4.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button4.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button4_Click);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(451, 287);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button4);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button3);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.progressBar1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar progressBar1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button3;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button4;
}
```